# Sumatoria con producto

Tags: python, bucles

Me quiero formar en ciencias para ello estoy practicando sumatorias y me cuesta avanzar.

El resultado no es el esperado, quiero implementarlo sin usar NumPy, resultados esperados:

1. `n = 2`, debería dar aprx = `-5.71121667`
2. `n = 3`, debería dar aprx = `-4.83927416`
3. `n = 4`, debería dar aprx = -`5.23488712`.

Éste es el código:

```
punto_a_evaluar = 0.8
n=3
aproximacion = 0
f_n = 1.0
diagonal = [-0.46828, -4.84156, -8.69656, -9.6882]
vector = [0.5, 1.0, 1.1, 1.3, 1.6]
for i in range(n+1):
  f_n = diagonal[i];     
  for j in range(1,i+1):   
    if j != i:
      f_n = f_n * (punto_a_evaluar - vector[j-1])
  aproximacion = aproximacion + f_n

print(aproximacion)
```

[image: Ecuacion]

Comment: A veces es difícil ayudar sin conocer más información de la entrada y su equivalente en la fórmula. Asumo que x es punto_a_evaluar. ¿f_0^{[n]}?

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres hacer el sumatorio de `i=0` a `i=n-1`, deberías cambiar el bucle. Tu código es algo así:

```py
n=3
for i in range(n+1):
    print(i)
#Salida: 0,1,2,3
```

Pero el `+1` te sobraría, ya que solo quieres iterar hasta `n-1` de acuerdo con la fórmula.

```py
n=3
for i in range(n):
    print(i)
```

A parte de eso un truco bastante útil es el uso de los operadores `*=` y `+=` por lo que podrías reescribir tu código de la siguiente manera. Te recomiendo leer sobre los [operadores de asignación](https://cursospython.com/operadores-de-asignacion/).

```py
aproximacion += f_n
```

```py
f_n *= (punto_a_evaluar - vector[j])
```

Por otro lado en la línea `for j in range(1,i+1):` y de acuerdo con la fórmula que proporcionas, debería ser `for j in range(1,n):`

Resulta un poco complicado entender lo que quieres hacer, ¿podrías poner un ejemplo o tal vez explicar mejor la fórmula?